# Anti derivatives of functions with Laurent series expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am given the functions $\mathrm{f}(z)=\frac{1}{z(1-z^2)}$ and $\mathrm{g}(z)=\frac{1}{z^2(1-z^2)}$.
I am then asked to find the laurent series on the punctured disc with radius 1 and 0 as the center. I found this to be:
$f(z)=z^{-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{2n+1}$ and $g(z)=z^{-2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{2n}$.
Then I am asked to argue if the functions have an anti derivative on the disc and if they have it on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{-1,0,1\}$.
My first thought is that g has an anti derivative on the disc because we can find the anti derivative of all the terms. While f doesn't have one because we can't find one for the $z^{-1}$-term. but what about on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{-1,0,1\}$? Do I have to find the laurent series outside the disc aswell, or is there a more direct way to see this? I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: The candidate for an antiderivative of $\frac1z$ is $\log(z)$.  But $\log(z)$ has branch points at $z=0$ and $z=\infty$ which results in a branch cut that passes through the disk.  $f(z)$ does have an antiderivative on the set $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$.

Comment: If $\displaystyle f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges for $r < |z| < R$ then $f(z)-\frac{a_{-1}}{z}$ is the derivative of $$ \sum_{n=-\infty, n \ne -1}^\infty a_n \frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}$$ which converges and is analytic for $r < |z| < R$. Since $\int_{|z|=r} \frac{dz}{z} = 2i\pi$, $\frac{1}{z}$ doesn't have a primitive on any such annulus, and you have the general result about Laurent series